# Проблема с русским языком в json через python

Tags: python, json

Итак, вот мой код в python:

```
with open("notverified.json", "r") as file:
    dict_data = json.load(file)

dict_data['test2'] = {'тест': 'успешно', 'точно': 'да'}

with open("notverified.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(dict_data, file, ensure_ascii=False)
```

На выходе должно получиться:

```
{"test": {"тест": "успешно", "точно": "да"}, "test2": {'тест': 'успешно', 'точно': 'да'}}
```

Но, увы, получается:

```
{"test": {"тест": "успешно", "точно": "да"}, "test2": {"����": "�������", "�����": "��"}}
```

Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы не было вопросиков? Как я понимаю, проблема с encoding, но я его попробовал...

Comment: Какая у вас операционка? Чем вы смотрите файл, который получается? В какой кодировке вы его открываете на просмотр - такую и нужно указывать при записи в файл.

Comment: Да, и не надо писать "я пробовал" без подробностей. Нужно приводить конкретный код, который вы пробовали и писать - какой результат получился. Так гораздо проще диагностировать проблему.

Comment: Проверьте, станет ли правильно работать, если указать кодировку при открытии файла при чтении и записи: `open("notverified.json", "r", encoding="utf-8")` `open("notverified.json", "w", encoding="utf-8")`

Answer (score 0):

столкнулся с подобной проблемой при получении данных от клиента (на сервере python работал) - данные отсылались как utf-8, а питоша их воспринимал как cp-1252

помогло такое решение: перевести в байты, декодировать в utf-8

```
sys.stdin.buffer.read(int(os.environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', 0))).decode('utf-8')
```

вам скорее всего нужно реализовать подобный подход

Comment: извини за тупой для тебя вопрос, но я вообще не понимаю эту строчку. Можно ли инструкцию по её использованию, или, на крайняк, документацию?

Comment: я просто  сказал где можно покопать
для начала просто в Notepad сохраните файл в разных кодировках и посмотрите какая сработает - какую именно кодировку подхватывает питон
мое предложение было считать побайтно и сконвертировать буфер с Utf-8

Comment: извини, я не понимаю, как это сделать .-.

Answer (score 0):

Что бы записать русские символы в метод open нужно передать `encoding='utf-8'`

```
import json

dict_data = {'тест': 'успешно', 'точно': 'да'}

with open("notverified.json", "w", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    json.dump(dict_data, file, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: При чтении тоже кодировку нужно указать, иначе будет читать в неправильной кодировке, потом перезаписывать эти кракозябры в файл.